# Возможно сделать тоже самое но через ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xhr

С использованием jquery

```js
let url = "test.xlsx",
  oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = (e) => {
  let arraybuffer = oReq.response,
    data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer),
    arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);

  let bstr = arr.join(""),
    workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
      type: "binary"
    }),
    first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0],
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name],
    obj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
};

oReq.send();
```

Сделал так

```js
function ajaxRequest() {

  $.get('test.xlsx', (response) => {
    let data = new Uint8Array(response),
      arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);

    let bstr = arr.join(""),
      workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
        type: "binary"
      }),
      first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0],
      worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name],
      obj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
    });
};
ajaxRequest();
```

Но `console.log(worksheet);` видит пустой объект.

Comment: что именно? у вас и так аякс используется

Comment: @ThisMan, осмелюсь предположить что автор хочет узнать как данный запрос будет выглядеть на `jquery`

Comment: @ InDevX. да на jq

Comment: все что до строки `data = new ... ` удаляете и оборачиваете  в `$.get(url, function(response){ ..... })`. `send` в конце тоже удаляете

Comment: @teran сделал пример, но data = new Uint8Array(response) пусто.

Comment: В response "абра-кадабра" выходит

Comment: Что то с типом данных делать надо, прописывал "arraybuffer", но ни чего не происходит.